# Possible to apache mod_autoindex and mod_dir to return directory listing via AJAX?

Tags: apache, mod-autoindex

This probably sounds silly, after all I could generate the file listing via PHP, right?

But I am becoming more and more fascinated with what all can be accomplished with just Apache and JQuery alone.  I've been reading documentation and it seems like things are SO VERY close, but I am obviously missing a few things.

- First, can I set a directory listing to a "path" or file name,
  overwriting the default, "index.html"? In particular, I am trying to
  configure any request ending in "ndx.mnu" to return the directory
  listing:

  "DirectoryIndex ndx.mnu"

...does not accomplish that.  Anyideas?

- Second, does anyone know of a way to impose a numerical sort similar
  to the way in which VersionSort works for files?  Right now:

  "foo-1, foo-2"

sorts correctly but what if I want to force:

```
"foo-1, bar-2"
```

to be order returned?

Trying to make something with as few moving parts as possible.  Any pointers to read up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well for the second part, you want to sort by the number rather than the letters correct? You should be able to read the string backwards and sort from end to beginning. Using `strrev()` to reverse it, you can write a sorting algorithm to do that.

Or if all the file use the '-#' notation then `$num = explode('-', $string);` and sort by `$num[1]` (which should be the number on the end) though if some file names contain multiple '-' you could use regular expressions.